# How to record desktop in .flv format?

Tags: desktop-recording

I tried to record my desktop on Ubuntu with 2 tools:

- [Recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)
- [Kazam screencaster](https://launchpad.net/kazam)

But, output video of Recordmydesktop is [`.ogv` format](http://diigo.com/0rue2). And ouput video of Kazam screencaster is `.mp4` and `.webm` format. I need output video after recording process in `.flv` format. I don't want to format them to `.flv`.

How to record desktop in `.flv` format?

Comment: covert the ogg to flv using ffmpeg. [ffmpeg -i file.ogg file.flv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems every ScreenCaster on Ubuntu saves in ogg format. You could easily convert your videos with `ffmpeg`, but if you don't want to do it (why?), you have probably only one alternative: [vnc2flv](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/index.html).

There are a couple of requirements (they could be easily installed from official repos):

1) [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/)

2) [Python](http://www.python.org/download/) (2.4+)

Download the package from the developer at http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/index.html#install, extract the archive and (as the developer explains on his site), use python to install the app as:

```
python setup.py install
```

And you're done. The app run only by command line. You may find useful instructions on developer's site or by watching this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/v/DcijI6EagYI&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0

Comment: thank for your support. I tried ffmpeg convert and x11vnc.